# USB Boot Menu made with EasyBCD does not display

Tags: multi-boot, usb-flash-drive, bcd, easybcd

Using EasyBCD I have created a bootable USB Drive.

I am able to boot to the USB drive on my PCs (tried multiple computers) but when the USB's boot menu should display all I get is a cursor like this: `__` and that's it.

I've rebuilt the boot setup several times and on two different USB drives. But the menu never shows.

I have also used [Visual BCD Editor](https://www.boyans.net/VisualBCD_doc.htm) to look at the settings and cannot find anything out of order.

Also [I posted a thread on the EasyBCD forum](https://neosmart.net/forums/threads/usb-boot-menu-is-all-gibberish.14346/), but I'm not getting any help there, so I am posting here.  Also, I have [reviewed this post](https://superuser.com/questions/501271/windows-boot-menu-doesnt-appear-when-booting), but the scope is different than my problem here.

The only thing I can figure is something is the matter with this kind of USB drive?  I have tried two different drives: Silicon Power Jewel J80 (32GB USB 3.0) and have tried configuring the menu both using a 2.0 port AND a 3.0 port.

How can I get the menu to show?  Or can I discover why it *does not* show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!  There was a bug in the way EasyBCD loads a newly deployed BCD store.

After you deploy the BCD store just ignore the messagebox asking you to load the store, choose Select Store from the File Menu and load it that way.

[More details in the other thread](https://neosmart.net/forums/threads/usb-boot-menu-is-all-gibberish.14346/#post-85825).